# Average over row values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The requirement am having seems to be pretty trivial, but somehow am unable to get it working.

I have some string values in a row, which i want to convert to a int after substituting the string portion and then average the output value. Sample table data and non-working formula is as follows. Any help in this regards would be greatly appreciated

```
Header|col1|col2|col3
Time|10min|11min|9min

Formula: =AVERAGE(SUBSTITUTE(B2:D2,"mins",""))
```

Answer (score 1):

To force Excel to consider a string as a number, either multiply by 1 or use a double minus sign. You can then use an array formula, or just a helper row.

In row 3, type `=--LEFT(A2,FIND(A2,"m")-1)`. Then just average the values that you get.

Please note that this assumes all of your minute values follow the format 'number then "min"'.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula works if you add the -- and put it in as an array formula (remembering to put "min" not "mins")

```
=AVERAGE(--SUBSTITUTE(B2:D2,"min",""))
```

have to enter it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>